# Динамическое смещение элементов по вертикали CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css-grid

Как реализовать динамическое смещение элементов по вертикали с помощью CSS Grid?
Пример структуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное никак, данный layout называется `masonry`.

Comment: Без js есть только один способ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns. И то если вам не так и важен порядок блоков